# Run timed function before continuing with the while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

im trying to call a function using `threading.timer` within a `while loop`, i expect it to halt the while loop first and wait until the function within the timer fires up then continue the loop. But it seems that my expectation and my code doesn't align with each other. I would appreciate assistance with this. Thanx

code:

```
import threading

def test():
    print("Updating....")

def cont():
    arg = raw_input("Update File(y/n): ")
    print(arg)
    if arg == 'y':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def printit():
    while cont():
        print("Auto update every 10 sec!")
        threading.Timer(10.0, test).start()

    print('now its false')


printit()
```

I want the `test()` to be called first before running the loop once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current behaviour is expected because you are using the `threading` library.
When you do `threading.Timer(10.0, test).start()` you launch a **new** thread which will wait 10 seconds and then launch `test`. But as it is a new thread, not the base thread where you were running your loop, it will not be waited - this is what happens in **asynchronous** programming.

If you want your code to be run in a **synchronous** way, you can use a simple `time.sleep` for that:

```
import time

def printit():
    while cont():
        print("Auto update every 10 sec!")
        time.sleep(10.0)
        test()

    print('now its false')
```

Comment: ok, no wonder it's firing up differently, thanx for the explaination too!!!